# Where is information about the connection to DB located in Jasper markup?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

In Jasper Studio 6.6.0, you can configure the connection to the database and start using the data from there. When I finished the report in the studio, I took the `jrxml`-file and then used it in the project to print pdf-reports.

Does the `jrxml`-markup store information about the connection to the database that was used in the studio?

P.S. I've not found such information inside jrxml. Well, now it's not clear: why connection to a DB is implemented in Jasper Studio and demonstration of filling the report with data from there?

Comment: Connection to db can help you having the *preview* of your report, and also so that Jasper Studio know your object structure and give you autocompletion.

Comment: @matthiasbe Ok. May be there is any way to avoid DAO so fill report with data from database directly?

Comment: You can pass db connection to exporter (with JR API), no need to make DAO. The reference to the dataadapter stored at jrxml helping us to make a report quicker. You can find a ton of samples at SO and at vendor site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out later - the jrxml-markup only stores label that data should be taken from the database via connection. So when the function of forming the JasperPrint invoked you can pass the `java.sql.Connection` object as the last parameter:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperReport jReport, Map<String,Object> params, Connection connection)
```

And the data will be received from the database.